# win32 WM_NOTIFY Vs WM_COMMAND

Tags: winapi

This is an theory question released to control messages in win32 api.

What is the difference between `WM_COMMAND` and `WM_NOTIFY`?
When do we need to handle these messages and when do we choose to ignore them?.

This doubt arises because both these messages are sent when the user interacts with an control and both send the same information to the window procedure that is event type,control I'd and control handle either as an structure
(LPNMHDR in case of `WM_NOTIFY`) or directly (LPARAM handle to control and LOWORD (WPARAM) in case of `WM_COMMAND`)

With all these similarities why do we still use both together and not just depracate one ?

Comment: The first batch of UI conbtrols (Edit, Pusbutton etc.) send `WM_COMMAND`, which has notification type (such as `BN_CLICKED`) and sender (ID and handle) packed into the WPARAM and LPARAM message arguments. When more controls - including tree and list view common controls - were introduced, this mechanism wasn't sufficient anymore. `WM_NOTIFY` was introduced, allowing more parameters in an extensible way; e.g. `NMTVITEMCHANGED` and `NMLVITEM` contain different data (control- and notification-specific), but can both be handled safely through `WM_NOTIFY`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We use both due to reasons of backwards compatibility. New controls tend to use WM_NOTIFY (it is far more capable), but there are existing controls that send WM_COMMAND and MS is not going to change that.

I say that WM_NOTIFY is more capable because of its lParam being an NMHDR *, which if the NMHDR is the first member of a POD type (or standard layout in modern C++ terms) then you can cast the lParam to the actual type the control sent. All WM_COMMAND can provide is a command code and window handle.

As for when to handle them that is strictly a matter of need, if you need to deal with a particular action on part of a particular control then you handle the message, if not then you don't.

Comment: This is correct.  WM_COMMAND is older and is used with very simple controls (like pushbuttons and menu entries) to communicate that the user wants to do "the thing."  WM_NOTIFY came with the newer common controls in the Windows 95 era.  Because it can carry more information (via the pointer to a structure), it can express more complex interactions, like clicking on a column header in a list view.  You know which kind you'll get by reading the docs for the particular control.

Comment: So WM_NOTIFY is more versatile then. Is there a way to make any old style controls send WM_NOTIFY message maybe something with the window style in the CreateWindowEx() function or is control specific?

Comment: @RVISHAL "*Is there a way to make any old style controls send WM_NOTIFY message*" - no. "*is control specific?*" - yes. Read each control's documentation for details