# Understanding SendMessage wparam

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am working on an MFC project, which has the following code:

```
NMHDR pNMHDR;
pNMHDR.hwndFrom = GetSafeHwnd();
pNMHDR.idFrom = GetDlgCtrlID();
pNMHDR.code = EN_CHANGE;
GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_NOTIFY, (EN_CHANGE << 16) | GetDlgCtrlID(), ( LPARAM ) &pNMHDR);
```

Please help me in understanding what `(EN_CHANGE << 16) | GetDlgCtrlID()` does.

Comment: It packs two 16 bit message parameters into a 32 bit value. Normally one would use the `MAKEWPARAM()` macro for this.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanPotter .BTW I am an user of your file manager. :-)

Comment: The meaning of the `WPARAM` parameter on `SendMessage` largely depends on the type of the message. The documentation explains it  well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [`EN_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) documentation for standard EDIT controls:

> wParam
>
> The LOWORD contains the identifier of the edit control. The HIWORD specifies the notification code.

So, the code is taking the constant `EN_CHANGE`, shifting its bits to the left 16 places, and then OR'ing the bits of the control ID.  Thus, `EN_CHANGE` ends up in bits 16-31, and the control ID ends up in bits 0-15:

```
                              WPARAM
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|            EN_CHANGE          |             CtrlID            |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

However, the code *should* be using the [`MAKEWPARAM()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-makewparam) macro instead of shifting + OR'ing bits manually, eg:

```
GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_NOTIFY, MAKEWPARAM(GetDlgCtrlID(), EN_CHANGE), (LPARAM) &pNMHDR);
```

Now, that being said, a standard EDIT control sends `EN_CHANGE` via `WM_COMMAND`, not `WM_NOTIFY`.  But a standard *windowless* RICHEDIT control sends `EN_CHANGE` via `WM_NOTIFY`, which carries only the control ID by itself in the `wParam` parameter. The command ID is carried in the `NMHDR` struct pointed at by the `lParam` parameter (except, RICHEDIT uses the `CHANGENOTIFY` struct, which is unrelated to `NMHDR`).

So, this code's use of `EN_CHANGE` is clearly non-standard usage, using a customized parameter scheme.

Comment: It's a bit weird that EN_CHANGE is being sent via WM_NOTIFY and not WM_COMMAND.

Comment: @JonathanPotter it is not weird at all.  `EN_CHANGE` is just an informational notification,  not a request for action.

Comment: It is actually documented as coming via WM_COMMAND though.

Comment: @JonathanPotter a standard Edit control sends its [`EN_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) via `WM_COMMAND`, but a standard RichEdit control sends its [`EN_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change--rich-edit-control-) via `WM_NOTIFY` instead. `WM_COMMAND` is old, `WM_NOTIFY` was introduced to overcome `WM_COMMAND`'s shortcomings, so it is actually more preferred. See [win32 WM_NOTIFY Vs WM_COMMAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765995/).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Even so, for `WM_NOTIFY`, the `wParam` is just the control ID, not the control ID combined with the notification code. For `WM_NOTIFY`, the notification code goes into the `NMHDR.code`.

Comment: @RaymondChen true. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you  . @RemyLebeau  Please mention the correct usage. As I am using Richedit control should I use CHANGENOTIFY  structure instead of NMHDR. When handling OnNotify in the parent application , should I use the LOWORD and HIWORD for getting the respective information.

Comment: @SujayGhosh that depends. Why are you sending an `EN_CHANGE` message manually to begin with, instead of letting the control send it for you?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am trying to better on the application which uses this code. The class is derived from CRichEditCtrl  . Its available at https://dev.visucore.com/doom3/doxygen/_c_syntax_rich_edit_ctrl_8cpp_source.html .  The event OnChange is being used as a reflected message  of EN_CHANGE .

Comment: @SujayGhosh "*The class is derived from CRichEditCtrl*" - all the more reason to either 1) send EN_CHANGE using standard parameters (which this code is not), or 2) not sending the message manually at all, letting the control send it for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I did 2) to solve the problem. What should be the standard parameters as mentioned for 1)

Comment: @SujayGhosh it is documented in tbe links I provided earlier.